# How do you integrate chrome browser with sublime text for a better workflow

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, sublimetext

I need to know if i can integrate sublime text with chrome dev tools so that i can easily understand my elements and modify them too.
Better still,is there any way to use the chrome web tools as a text editor so that I can easily create and save webpages.

Answer (score 0):

Newer Chrome versions (Dev & Canary) have, if you enable Devtool experiments in flags, a "Workspace" tab in the options which allows you to specify certain folders that you can edit *inside devtools*. These show up in the filesystem tree of the "Sources" tab.

See https://plus.google.com/u/0/+GoogleChromeDevelopers/posts/644qQuBKZeL